# Javascript - await fetch response

Tags: javascript

I have a React-Native app and when the component mounts, I want to fetch data by calling a method in our services class, wait for that data to be returned, then set that data in setState({}). But setState({}) is called before the data is returned.

//Component class

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.getData();
}

async getData() {
    const data = await MyService.getData();
    this.setState({
        blah:data //undefined
    });
}
```

//Services Class

```
let MyService = {
    getData:function(){
        axios.get(url)

    .then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
            //do stuff
          return data;//need to set this to state back in component class
     })
     .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
     });   
      }
}
```

module.exports = MyService;

Comment: Why is `MyService.getData` an `async function` if you're not using `await`?

Comment: yeah that wasnt supposed be there. my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the `axios.get` call. Otherwise the `async function` will return an empty promise (promise with the `undefined` value).

```js
let MyService = {
  getData: function() {
    return axios.get(url)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        // do stuff
        return data; // need to set this to state back in component class
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });   
  }
}
```

If you return this axios call, it's itself a promise and you're not waiting until it resolves, so there's no need to use `async`.

Comment: :) anyone can forget simple thing